# QtCreator: no application project as a choice for new project

Tags: windows, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I have a problem that Qt doesn't let me create Qt application - there is no such option in "New Project" - but only under my Windows. Under Linux it works like a charm.

I have installed package Qt+QtCreator from official Qt's download page.

I have already looked it up on google and I found answers here, on stackoverflow, but everybody suggest to add Qt to build toolkits in configuration. That's not problem in my case - QtCreator detects my Qt automatically and correctly:

[image]

This still doesn't let me create Qt app:

[image]

(it's in polish, but it says that only possible projects are non-qt and imported projects).

I have checked if qmake.exe pointed by the Qt that QtCreator is using works - yes, it works.

What else can I check/do?

Comment: Odd. Do you have all the templates installed properly?

Comment: How can I check that? Note, that I didn't do any custom installation. I downloaded the installator that installs both Qt and QtCreator. This one to be precise: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.2/5.2.1/qt-opensource-windows-x86-mingw48_opengl-5.2.1.exe

Comment: Have you tried the 5.3.0 RC1 and see if that works?

Comment: I've tried 5.3.0 RC1 and the result was the same. Although I tried the original one (5.2.1) on Windows 7 and it works there! The problem is Windows XP. I didn't know that the support for XP was dropped... was it?

Comment: It is not tested anymore, so it may or may not work. As a development environment, it definitely is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, it seems that you are using Windows XP. That is not supported anymore. It was dropped a while ago. It may or may not work, but overall, it would be bad experience in the majority of the cases because things like your issue is also somewhat fundamental.

The currently supported Windows variants are Windows 7 and 8. I think it is a wise decision to upgrade if you can or look for an Integrated Development Environment that is still well supported on Windows XP. That means you could also get an older version of QtCreator, but it would probably be behind Qt 5 feature support now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the Windows XP. Using more recent Windows version fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can downgrade Qt to latest version which supports Windows XP (OpenGL?), AFAIK v5.1.1. It can be installed via current online installer.

Edit: but I found it's pretty unstable (hence I using Qt running on Linux via VirtualBox).